# Is creating interfaces for DAO justifiable whereas i have created DAO for services?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, architecture

We are revamping a new Service Oriented Architecture using Spring @Autowired by the @Service and @Component annotation.

I have been in the debate with my colleagues for not to have interfaces for each DAO's. Becuase for me it doesn't make any sense, whereas i have strongly support the fact of having Interfaces for Services, because of an abstract view with Autowiring.

This is as follows:

Controller (Consumer) < Service (Interface) by @Autowire annotation

Service Implementation (Implements Service) uses DAO using @Component Or @Repository.

Does my understanding of this architecture is correct or Am I missing really important architectural concept.

Comment: If you use a framework like JPA, Hibernate, MyBatis or another that support the DAO layer for you, then you don't need any DAO interface since the Services may access directly to this DAO layer. If you not or want/need to define behavior and business logic to define access, insert, update, delete, etc... of your tables (which should be in service layer, anyway), then create the DAO layer and define all he database access you want/need.

Comment: LuiggiMendoza: This absolutely meaning full, but as i have mentioned in my question about the creation of DAO layer, so my questions is more intended to have interfaces in the DAO layers, or I can use DAO by having @Component on DAOs.

Comment: Again, if you already use a framework like Hibernate or JPA that already abstracts the DAO layer, you won't need any interface for DAO, unless you want/need to create such e.g. a technical requirement for software architecture team. If you don't have such framework, create your DAO interfaces and annotate the implementations with [`@Repository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it doesn't seem likely, but I have had it happen where I wanted to implement a DAO using a different storage technology, or simply using JDBC instead of Hibernate because of a performance problem.

In a large app, everything's an interface. It makes your unit tests more flexible and gives you a better long-term path. The cost is only some extra classes and most IDEs help you maintain them.

Comment: I agree with your point @The Thom, but interfaces are something which we define when we have a lot of frequent changes as you have mentioned in your answer but In my application I don't have such kind of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

By referencing you DAO objects by interface from your services, you will have services that is much easier to write tests for.